# How to pair NFC and bluetooth via Negotiated handover

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

I want to pair keyboard and android phone.
I am the tag role in my EV board, not phone.
I can't refer the android sample code.

I already connected the bluetooth via simple tag by SSP spec.
But my friend told me Keyboard need the hash key to confirm.
I tried to use Negotiated handover(tag mode). 
The phone(LG G2) can't identify the tag format.

Finial, I found Handover spec indicated handover should use LLCP mode(P2P mode).
I am not sure about it.
Seldom people talk about keyboard and Negotiated handover in Tag.

My questions:

1. If pair by NFC, does keyboard need hash key or not? 
   If doesn't need, I can use simple tag mode to easily connect.
2. Does Negotiated handover use LLCP mode?

Thanks!!